# How to get this to work "SELECT COUNT(x) AS amount ... WHERE amount > 0"?

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Due to the syntax of mySQL this statement is not allowed (a counted element cannot be used within the WHERE part):

```
Illegal syntax:
SELECT COUNT(x) AS amount ... WHERE amount > 0
```

But how do I handle a COUNTed element via WHERE ?

Comment: Note that you probably intend to do WHERE x > 0. See my answer below for clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## edit

Note that your original query may not do what you think it does. You probably want `WHERE x > 0` instead:

```
SELECT COUNT(x) AS amount ... WHERE x > 0
```

This is because `HAVING amount > 0` is essentially meaningless if there are ANY x values greater than 0. MySQL will automatically group and include all of your rows, counting every one of them. It looks like you want to know the number of rows with a non-zero amount in x, so you need to specify with WHERE that only those rows should match the original criteria to be counted. See below for an example case of needing an aggregate function *with* HAVING.

## original answer:

You do this with `HAVING`. The syntax is exactly the same as `WHERE`, but it is evaluated after the aggregation.

```
SELECT COUNT(x) AS amount ... HAVING amount > 0
```

The difference is important, since it allows you to limit which rows are counted with WHERE, and then limit the rows returned with HAVING.

For instance, let's say I wanted to know how much money I made per department on sales of LESS THAN $10, only if it made more than $1000:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(amount) as total_sales
  ... 
WHERE amount < 10.0 
GROUP BY department 
HAVING total_sales > 1000.0
```

Comment: There is an implicit GROUP BY whenever you use an aggregate function.

Comment: If that wasn't clear, the answer is essentially yes. When your query includes an aggregating function, but no `GROUP BY` clause, it will "group" every row in the result set into 1 group, and you can use having.

Comment: All rows, one group. nothing to group on, essentially the group is defined by having met the WHERE criteria.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the info.  (And serves as a reminder for why I'm glad I'm not using mysql)

Comment: What else would you have it do? For example, the query: `select count(*) from table`, how would that not auto-aggregate? Or do you mean you want it to fail to run the query if you specify HAVING without a GROUP BY?

Comment: Right, it should raise an exception if someone specifies HAVING without GROUP BY.

Comment: I think that's a fair thing to want. Personally, I like the notion that HAVING is dependent on there *being* aggregation, and not dependent on syntax. count() causes aggregation, just like GROUP BY, so both create the opportunity for HAVING to be useful.

Comment: The problem with an automatic GROUP BY is that it's too easy to not do what the user wanted. It's better to ask the user to specify. Although... I can see some value in supporting a 'GROUP BY \*' syntax, to save the user from having to specify a bazillion columns when they *do* want the default Mysql behavior. I'd just rather specify what I want, than have my software guess and risk being wrong. Different strokes...

Comment: Without that * syntax (which is a cool idea, btw), you simply *could not* get what mysql does. Specifying a bunch of columns in GROUP BY would cause more groups, not fewer.

Comment: Oh right... Now I'm confused as to how this answers the question then.  I'll ponder it some more on my own... thanks.

Comment: Never mind... your recent update answers the question that was bubbling to the top of my mind.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COUNT(x) AS amount ... HAVING amount > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`HAVING`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html) for this query. It is same as `WHERE`, but specifically for `COUNT(x)`!

**SQL**

```
SELECT COUNT(x) AS amount ... HAVING amount > 0
```